# Create a confirmation message from model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have an app in Django that has multiple models. I have a particular model like this:

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
model_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
model_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Label 1")
model_counter = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('model_id', 'model_date ', 'model_counter ')
list_filter = (
    ('model_date', DropdownFilter)
)    
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    if 'delete_selected' in actions:
        del actions['delete_selected']
    return actions
readonly_fields = ['model_counter ']
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

What I need is that the user confirm that he wants to save the model, even if the date is greater than today, in doing so the user can create a model that can be wrong for other users, but sometime it's correct that the date is greater than today.

I cannot use a custom HTML form, only the default one.

The user must interact someway with the page, and give direct aknowledgement that he knows that is saving a new model that can be dangerous for other users. The user must be able to abort the saving or modify the date.
So I tried to use another field of the model to store the counter:

```
def clean(self):
    condition = False
    if self.model_counter is None:
        condition = True
    else:
        condition = self.model_counter == 1

    if condition :
        self.model_counter = 1
        raise ValidationError("Attention, the date inserted is after the current date, click the SAVE button another time to proceed with the saving")
```

As a counter I use another field of the same model. I'm not able to make the updating of the counter working. From what I have understood, the lifecycle of validation prevent me to alter in the proper way the state of the istance of the model that the code it's saving, so the updating of the field model it's ignored.
There are is any way to achieve my goal? I used the model field for storing the value of counter because I'm not able in another way. I don't care  where is the counter. I don't care also to use the message system of Django or a popup. I need only to force the user under some condition to make an interaction that force him to continue or abort the saving.

**Edit**
I added also the code in the admin.py for more clearness. I modified only the models and the admin, invoke the command: *python3 manage.py inspectdb > models.py* and I got all the code generated. That it's the standard procedure for this things in my company. So I cannot add (or I don't how) code to the Web pages generated from Django.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best to use some JavaScript here. Where you add a `click` event to the submit button where a modal/dialag asks the user to confirm. If they say Yes, then you can submit the form.

For example with dialog (you can make it modal if you want):

HTML

```
<form id="myModelForm" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button id="myModelSave">{% trans "Save" %}</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
let saveButton = document.getElementById('myModelSave');
saveButton.onclick = function() {
    let accepted = confirm("Are you sure you want to save?");
    if (accepted) {
        document.getElementById('myModelForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Django create this Web Pages dinamically, if I had understand the process, so I can modifiy the creation of this Web Pages?